# List files without "." and ".."

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a file list excluding diretories like "." and "..".
I use the following code to do that:

```
   DIR *dir;   
   struct dirent *ent;

   dir = opendir(currentDir);

   if (dir != NULL)   
   {
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
      {

         if (ent->d_name == "." || ent->d_name == "..")
         {
            continue;
         }
      }
   }
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `strcmp` to compare strings.  Rather than this:

```
if (ent->d_name == ".")
```

you need this:

```
if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0)
```

Your code is comparing the pointers directly, rather than comparing the content of the strings.

See [the strcmp documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcmp` to do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to read files (except folders)

```
if (ent->d_type == DT_REG) // DT_REG stands for regular files
{
  printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
}
```

If you need to read folder names

```
if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR) // DT_DIR stands for directory
{
  printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string is not native c data-type, string is represented as collection of characters. So to compare string there are no operators rather function, **strcmp()** for more information.