# how can i get all file name in a directory without getting "." and ".." in C

Tags: c, linux

I am working with Linux system.

```
 DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {           
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
```

I get `"."` , `".."` and some file names as a result. 
How can I get rid of `"."` and `".."`? 
I need those file names for further process. 
What's the type of `ent->d_name`?? Is it a string or char?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991334/members-of-dirent-structure . If `d_name` were a char, then using `%s` to print it would be undefined behaviour (not to mention using one char to store an entire filename would require some amazing data compression algorithms).

Comment: "What's the type of `ent->d_name`?? Is it a string or char?" - have you read the documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List files without "." and ".."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138624/list-files-without-and)

Answer (score 2):

Read the man page of readdir, get this:

```
struct dirent {
               ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
               off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
               unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
               unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                              by all file system types */
               char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
           };
```

So `ent->d_name` is a char array. You could use it as a string, of course.

To get rid of `"."` and `".."`:

```
while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {  
if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0 )
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
```

**Update**

The resulting `ent` contains file names and file folder names. If folder names are not needed, it is better to check `ent->d_type` field with `if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR)`.

Comment: Of course string types don't exist in C anyway (only in C++), so all strings are effectively just a character array.

Comment: @UltimateGobblement Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp` :

```
while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {  
if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0)         
    //printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
```